# Centering of stacked bussproofs trees

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, logic, bussproofs

I like to stack proof rules build with bussproofs vertically. In order to use tags and labels I enclose the proof tress inside a equation, which is why I introduced the rawprooftree environment as suggested earlier in [Numbering sequent proofs like equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58033/numbering-sequent-proofs-like-equations). Directly enclosing bussproofs trees does not work.

However, the resulting stack is ugly, because the rules are not centered. How can I achieve that the proof trees are centered relative to each other?

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,headsepline,footsepline,DIV=13,BCOR=12mm,bibliography=toc,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{bussproofs} % sequent-calculus-style proofs

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain, width=.9\textwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newenvironment{rawprooftree}
{\varwidth{.9\linewidth}\centering\leavevmode}
{\DisplayProof\endvarwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h] 
        \centering
        \begin{small}
            \fbox{\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}%
                \begin{equation*}\tag{$\forall$R}\label{rule:forallR}%
                    \begin{rawprooftree}%
                        \def\defaultHypSeparation{\hskip .02in}%
                        \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash \varphi_x^y, \Delta$}%
                        \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \forall x. \varphi, \Delta$}%
                    \end{rawprooftree}%
                \end{equation*}%
                \begin{equation*}\tag{CEL}\label{rule:CEL}%
                    \begin{rawprooftree}%
                        \def\defaultHypSeparation{\hskip .02in}%
                        \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash C(Q), \Delta$}%
                        \AxiomC{$P \leftrightarrow Q$}%
                        \BinaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash C(P), \Delta$}%
                    \end{rawprooftree}%
                \end{equation*}%
            \end{subfigure}}%
        \end{small}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `0.45\textwidth` is too small.

Using `0.5\textwidth` solves the issue (for the particular trees). Also the input can be vastly simplified. The `varwidth` is actually not necessary, at least in this application.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,headsepline,footsepline,DIV=13,BCOR=12mm,bibliography=toc,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{bussproofs} % sequent-calculus-style proofs

\newenvironment{rawprooftree}{}{\DisplayProof}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering\small

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}
  \begin{gather*}
    \tag{$\forall$R}\label{rule:forallR}
    \begin{rawprooftree}
      \def\defaultHypSeparation{\hskip .02in}
      \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash \varphi_x^y, \Delta$}
      \UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash \forall x. \varphi, \Delta$}
    \end{rawprooftree}
  \\
    \tag{CEL}\label{rule:CEL}%
    \begin{rawprooftree}
      \def\defaultHypSeparation{\hskip .02in}
      \AxiomC{$\Gamma \vdash C(Q), \Delta$}
      \AxiomC{$P \leftrightarrow Q$}
      \BinaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash C(P), \Delta$}
    \end{rawprooftree}
  \end{gather*}
  \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}
\end{minipage}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much to have read my comment in chat.